# Is $\sum_{p\text{ prime, } p \geq 2}\frac{(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}}{p}$ convergent or divergent??

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Is $\sum\limits_{\text{p prime}, p \geq 2}\frac{(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}}{p}$ convergent or divergent?

So far I have that

\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{\text{p prime}, p \geq 2} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}}{p} =& \frac{(-1)^{\frac{3}{8}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{\text{p prime}, p > 2} \frac{(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}}{p}\\
=& \frac{(-1)^{\frac{3}{8}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{\text{p prime}, p > 2}\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\frac{1}{p}\\
=& \frac{(-1)^{\frac{3}{8}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{\substack{\text{p prime}, p > 2, \\ \text{ 2 a quadratic residue (mod p)}}}\frac{1}{p} \\
&- \sum\limits_{\substack{\text{p prime}, p > 2, \\ \text{ 2 a quadratic nonresidue (mod p)}}}\frac{1}{p}\\
\end{align}

I'm guessing these two sums should cancel - I remember a theorem of some sort which said that the number of quadratic residues 2(mod p) for all prime's $p > 2$ is $\sim \frac{\pi(x)}{2}$

Am I on the right track? or should I have done this differently? Any help and comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a series behaves like $\log L(1,\chi)$ where $\chi$ is the Dirichlet character $\pmod{8}$ associated with the Legedre symbol
$$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}, $$
hence the series is convergent.

We also have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}-\frac{1}{8n+3}-\frac{1}{8n+5}+\frac{1}{8n+7}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\log\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2-\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: Thank you, would you mind elaborating how this series $\sim \text{log }L(1,\chi)$? I think I know how to show that $L(1,\chi)$ is finite.

Comment: Just write $L(1,\chi)$ as a Euler product, then take the logarithm.

Comment: $L(1,\chi)=\prod\limits_p \frac{1}{1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p}}$ so now expressing it as an euler product and taking logs, I get, $\text{log }L(1,\chi) = \sum\limits_{p} \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n} \frac{\chi(p)^n}{p^n}$ am I supposed to find a $\chi(2) = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$ term somewhere in this sum? I am sorry, I seem to be struggling showing that they are asymptotically equivalent.

Comment: @Pablo: the key fact is that the terms corresponding to values of $n\geq 2$ give a bounded contribute, hence $\sum_p\frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ is $\log\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}\right)+O(1).$